# Dropdown Menu timing out issue

Tags: javascript

I'm not quite sure why my menus are timing out incorrectly. As soon as you hover over a menu heading to see the dropdown it flashes its submenu so that you can't select a link from it. Any ideas why?  I've been working on this for too long now.

```
var menuTimeout = '';
$('.nav_click').bind({
mouseover: function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('submenus') == true){
        var whichMenu = $(this).attr('id');
        var displayMenu = '';//yes its blank for a reason
        if(whichMenu == 'navi2'){displayMenu = 'menu1';}
        if(whichMenu == 'navi3'){displayMenu = 'menu2';}
        if(whichMenu == 'navi4'){displayMenu = 'menu3';}
        if(whichMenu == 'navi5'){displayMenu = 'menu4';}
        if(displayMenu != '')
        {
            var leftOffset = ($(this).position().left-5);
            var topOffset = ($(this).offset().top+$(this).height()-10);
            $('#'+displayMenu).css({"display":"block", "position":"absolute", "left":leftOffset+"px", "top":topOffset+"px"});
        }
    }
    var menuitem = $(this).attr('id');
    if(menuitem == "navi1"){$(this).css({"background-position":"0 -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi2"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-100px -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi3"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-230px -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi4"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-420px -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi5"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-524px -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi6"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-638px -63px"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi7"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-737px -63px"});}
},
mouseout: function(){
   if($('.submenublock').is(":visible") == true){menuTimeout = setInterval(function() {$('.submenublock').fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"}); clearInterval(menuTimeout);}, 1500);}
    var menuitem = $(this).attr('id');
    if(menuitem == "navi1"){$(this).css({"background-position":"0 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi2"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-100px 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi3"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-230px 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi4"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-420px 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi5"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-524px 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi6"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-638px 0"});}
    if(menuitem == "navi7"){$(this).css({"background-position":"-737px 0"});}
},
click: function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('rel');
}

});
$('.submenublock ul').bind({
mouseover: function(){
clearInterval(menuTimeout);
},
mouseout: function(){
menuTimeout = setInterval(function()                                                             {$('.submenublock').fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"}); clearInterval(menuTimeout);}, 500);   
}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the mouseover handler is triggering the mouseout handler.

When you hover over a top-level item the following code eventually gets executed:

```
 $('#'+displayMenu).css({"display":"block", "position":"absolute", "left":leftOffset+"px", "top":topOffset+"px"}
```

This causes the top-level item to lose focus (for some reason), which makes the "mouseout" code fire right away, fading out the menu that just opened in 0.5 seconds.

I tried commenting out the fade out/delay line in mouseout and this behavior stops (granted, the menus never go away either, but we have pinpointed the problem)

```
mouseout: function(){
  // if($('.submenublock').is(":visible") == true){menuTimeout = setInterval(function() {$('.submenublock').fadeOut('slow').css({"display":"none"}); clearInterval(menuTimeout);}, 1500);}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are un-hiding/moving/displaying another dom element under the mouse, which is not a child of the div that contains the mouseover?  That will trigger a mouseout.

Comment: here's the website kansasoutlawwrestling.com